# How to modify a var in a controller when something happens in a service?

Tags: angularjs

Basically I want to be able to broadcast from a service when something happens.
What's the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's as a result of an async call initiated by your controller, use promises (google up on q and resolve).

If it's as a result of something occurring as a result of something not initiated from your controller, use watch. You can assign a scope variable to point to your service to watch variables exposed by the service (and bind to them in views).

Code idea for the second pattern:

```
function MyController($http, MyService) {
    $scope.myService = MyService;
    $scope.$watch("myService.aVariableInTheService", function() {
        console.log("aVariableInTheService has changed!");
    }
}
```

And in the view:

```
<div>A variable is {{myService.aVariableInTheService}}</div>
```

Comment: This thing works ? I was using broadcast and rootscope ?

Comment: Unless I made some typing error - yes it works :-) (for more examples you can check one of my repos: https://github.com/osirisguitar/GuitarJournal/). I think watches are generally better than event emitted - it's easier to read the code and the couplings are not as global as event emissions tend to be.

Comment: basically I want to keep a variable in sync with localStorage updated whenever my service modifies it.